# Terminate the current camel exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I am processing file in cluster environment. The cluster works fine. It is being processed on Only one server. 
But on the second server It identifies as duplicates but still execute the form route `delete=true`

**ERROR:**

> org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot delete file:

I am setting header **CamelRouteStop** to true but the exchange still try's to delete a file, instead of stop executing the route.

All I need is to end the route if it is duplicate.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="smb:url?delete=true"/>
        <idempotentConsumer messageIdRepositoryRef="myRepo">
            <header>messageId</header>
            <setHeader headerName="fileExist">
                    <simple>true</simple>
                </setHeader>
        </idempotentConsumer>
        <when>
                <simple>${header.fileExist} == null</simple>
                <log message="File ${header.CamelFileName} processing/processed by other Nodes - DUPLICATE" loggingLevel="INFO" />
                <setHeader headerName="CamelRouteStop">
                    <simple  <simple resultType="java.lang.Boolean">true</simple>>true</simple>
                </setHeader>
            </when>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Do you have a cluster consuming the same directory, that's it? If it is, you could implement a read lock during the read. http://camel.apache.org/file2.html (see the `readLock` property).

Comment: I tried couple of options below but no luck: delay=600000&readLockCheckInterval=20000&readLockTimeout=60000&readLock=changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CamelRouteStop you need to use `setProperty`, not `setHeader`.